# Limiting amount of times a variable can appear in PuLP Optimizer

Tags: python, linear-programming, pulp

**My Problem:**

I am following [this tutorial](https://medium.com/ml-everything/using-python-and-linear-programming-to-optimize-fantasy-football-picks-dc9d1229db81) to make a PuLP optimizer (Credit to Branko Blagojevic, awesome job!). However, there is one issue with this tutorial. The final output returns the same player twice (DeSean Jackson is in FLEX *and* WR - this cannot be, as each spot must consist of a unique player). So, my question is, how can I ensure that the FLEX spot is unique from all other positions? I know there are problems similar to this, but they don't exactly match the structure of my specific problem.

**What I Have Tried:**

I figured I could maybe delete a player from the `_vars` dictionary once they have been selected to the optimal solution when setting up the reward, like so

```
del _vars['__player__']
```

But then I realized the solution itself isn't an iterative process like setting up the reward, so this won't work. I then figured I could maybe set a constraint to make sure each name only appears once:

```
# this is how _vars is defined
_vars = {k: LpVariable.dict(k, v, cat="Binary") for k, v in points.items()}

current = current.set_index(['displayName','position'])
pairs = current.index   # tuples of (name, pos)
name_set = current.index.unique(0)


# Setting up the reward
for k, v in _vars.items():
    costs += pulp.lpSum([salaries[k][i] * _vars[k][i] for i in v])
    rewards += pulp.lpSum([points[k][i] * _vars[k][i] for i in v])
    prob += pulp.lpSum([_vars[k][i] for i in v]) <= pos_num_available[k]

# i think the solution is something like this
for name in name_set:
    prob += pulp.lpSum([_vars[n, p] for (n, p) in pairs if n == name]) <=1

    
prob += pulp.lpSum(rewards)
prob += pulp.lpSum(costs) <= SALARY_CAP
```

But I can't quite get it - I think I need to alter `pairs` so that it matches the structure of `_vars`? Either way, I believe I'm very close. The concept of adding a constraint for each name to only appear one time is the right way I'm almost certain. Just need some help finishing the execution. Thanks!

Comment: That looks fine/correct to me.  there are probably a couple of alternatives, but they will lead to the same math model going into the solver.  When you tried that, did you get duplicate names?  Have you checked to ensure that `pairs` is properly constructed and contains the `FLEX` position from the modified `df`?

Comment: I get a key error - I'm unsure if I need to shape `_vars` to match `pairs` or vice versa (`_vars` has the LP variables and `pairs` just has the position for the player

Comment: edit your post and show how `_vars` is defined.  It should be from all "legal" combos of `n, p` which should == pairs, so you missed something.

Comment: I used the exact code from the tutorial, so it can be found there. I can also add it to my OP if you'd like.

Comment: It is almost a certainty that `points.items() != pairs`.  You might make a set out of each of them and look for differences by subtracting one set from the other.  Perhaps `points.items()` is constructed to contain pairs that aren't in the index?  Because you are using `points.items()` to make your variable, use that instead of `pairs` in the constraint statement .... `for (n, p) in points.items()...`.  And do the side experiment to see why they are different and convince yourself it is OK or needs a fix.

Comment: hmmm since `points.items()` is broken out by position, wouldn't the indexes be different than `name_set`?  Just simply adding `points.items()` to the constraint set doesn't effectively change anything in the results but rather just adds a bunch of empty constraints. Need I add the `name_set` loop to the `_vars.items()` loop? I don't think that would help... hm...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249734/discussion-between-airsquid-and-bismo).